# Undesired bullet format change after pasting (Word 2016)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am loosing bullet formatting copying it from specific files.

There is a VBA code which is copying whole word documents and pasting it into one word document. There is a problem that in some of the source files We have a squared bullets, which change into circle after pasting to main document. I was trying to copy and paste it manually using "keep source formatting" but without any luck. Strange thing is that pasting from some of the documents doesn't lose the format on bullets. Maybe there is some workaround to have exactly the same formatting as it is in source.

```
doc.Range.Copy
Set pasteBriefAt = template.Range
pasteBriefAt.InsertAfter (vbCrLf)
pasteBriefAt.End = pasteBriefAt.End - 1
pasteBriefAt.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
pasteBriefAt.Paste
```

[image: source document]

[image: how it look like after pasting]

Comment: Did the suggested answer help you? If yes, please mark it as the answer. If not, please explain how it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the FormattedText method. For example:

```
With DocTgt.Range
  .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
  .Range.Characters.Last = DocSrc.Range.FormattedText
End With
```

Comment: I tried your code, but instead of table the pasted area was only a bolded text.

Comment: If all you got was some bolded text, then that's all the document defined by DocSrc contained.